# Insertar datos con AngularJS

Tags: html5, angularjs, post, http, function

Estoy tratando de realizar un post con AngularJS, pero los datos no son insertados. ¿Qué puede faltarme en el código o que habría que rectificar? El método es addPost.

**controller.js:**

```
angular.module("Practicando AngularJS", []).controller("FirstController", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.newPost = {};
    $http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            $scope.posts = response.data;
        })
        //.error(function(err) {
        //});
        $scope.addPost = function () {
            $http.post("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", {
                title: $scope.newPost.title,
                body: $scope.newPost.body,
                userId: 1
            })
            .then(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.post.push($scope.newPost); 
                $scope.newPost = {}; 
            })
            .error(function (error, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }

});
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="Practicando AngularJS">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS - http</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="controller.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="FirstController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="newPost.title"><br />
    <textarea ng-model="newPost.body"></textarea>
    <button ng-click="addPost()">Enviar</button>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="post in posts">
            <h2>{{post.title}}</h2>
            <p>
                {{post.body}}
            </p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un typo en tu código.

Es `posts` no `post`.

```
 $scope.posts.push($scope.newPost)
```